# Bad user account permissions

Tags: permissions, ftp

I made a user account in linux, and when i login to it through shell, it has access to all the root files and folders. how can i lock the user account to its /home/ folder, and make it so it cant CD into / ?

Ive tried to chroot it, ive tried chmod and chown, it will not work.

Comment: Is this FTP? SFTP?  Direct SSH access?  We need more information.  (You'll likely have to do a specialized set of chrooting for each type of access mechanism you access the system with, shell access included.  Though, shell access is that much harder to jail.

Comment: Im trying to setup ftp on a specific user account thats not "root". I used vsftpd, but that user account could access the entire root folder. i even had the chroot toggles in the conf file set to the home/$USER directory.

I then logged into the user account, and it has a $ indicating its not root. but it can go in and touch all the root files

Comment: My goal is to make a FTP server with an FTP account of some kind that can access and ONLY access /home/username_here/* and nothing outside of /home/ and cant access a different user account

ive read many guides and nothing answers my complaint and it all works the same

Comment: And you've done something like [this has suggested](https://linuxhint.com/vsftpd_chroot_home_dir/) to do the chroot processes?

Comment: Also, you should consider using SFTP, not FTP, because FTP is inherently insecure.

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]